# How can I get the unread emails using Graph

Tags: azure

We have a portal in our company and our users login using their corporate account that is synced with Azure AD. We want to  show an indicator on our portal of their unread emails. Do I need to get all email and count the ones that are unread on can I filter on unread and get a count on the collection? Both solution will deliver high traffic so is there a more performance way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a messages call with Graph also has the unreademail count in  UnreadItemCount. Best way is to use the NUGET package Microsoft.Graph, make a call, cast the result to mailfolder and retrieve the unread email count:

```
       HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        //Get 10 Unread Messages
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> call = httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/Inbox");
        call.Wait();
        var responseUnread = call.Result;
        if (responseUnread.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string s = await responseUnread.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //Deserialize to Microsoft.Graph.MailFolder NUGET:Microsoft.Graph
            var mf = serializer.Deserialize<MailFolder>(s);

            unreadMail = mf.UnreadItemCount;
        }
```